# Screen Layout problems when migrating my app from Xcode 5.1 to Xcode 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

My app runs perfectly in Xcode 5.1 in all the simulators.I tried running exactly the same app with no changes at all in Xcode 6.0 and my layout looks totally messed up in all the simulators. I use separate .xib files and the content is populated in code. Even trying to do simple stuff like centering a label on the screen like

```
lblName.center=CGPointMake(kScreenWidth/2, kScreenHeight/2);
 where kscreenwidth and kscreenheight are 

#define kScreenWidth [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
#define kScreenHeight [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
```

did not show up correctly in any of the iOS 8.0 simulators.Can anyone explain me what is going on. Also I have added launch image of correct sizes and also selected Auto Layout in all the .xib files.What am i missing and why is the layout not as in previous iOS version? Have anyone encountered similar problems? Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define these two dimensions correctly or just typo?

#define kScreen**Width** [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.**height**

#define kScreen**Height** [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.**width**